# Extract files from a zip into a jar archive

Tags: c#

I have a little problem!
I work on a Selfmade Minecraft launcher in c# with the DotNetZip Library.
So, this Launcher has an Option for update that it downloads a .zip from a server and should extract all files from the zip into the minecraft.jar! but an error states "The file already exist" or it create's a folder called minecraft.jar......
Is there a possible way to extract files from a zip archive directly into a other zip archive? (Because a .jar is nearly the same as a .zip)
here is the download and extraxt code(dont wonder bout some texts's which are in german):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = true; //Dient nur zur Deko
    label1.Text = "Download......";
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/97421059/Test.zip"), @"Test.zip"); //Der Link sollte für die Zukünftigen Versionen immer gleich sein!
    button3.Visible = false;

}


private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Entpacken....."; //In der Box
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
    button3.Visible = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Download abgeschlossen!!\n\rBitte warte bis der Launcher die Dateien entpackt hat."); // Erklärt sich von selbst
    string ExistingZipFile = @"Test.zip";
    string sourceDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string TargetDirectory = (sourceDir + "minecraft.jar");
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
    {


        // ab hier komm der restliche script
        // bei dem man eig. nix einstellen soll 
        foreach (ZipEntry ze in zip)
        {
            ze.Extract(TargetDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);

        }
        MessageBox.Show("Entpacken der Dateien abgeschlossen!");
        label1.Text = "Entpacken abgeschlossen!";
    }


}
```

After i pasted GemHunter1 Code(i hope i filled the names in the right position) i have no errors, but in the minecraft.jar is still nothing from the downloadet zip

```
private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Entpacken....."; //In der Box
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
    button3.Visible = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Download abgeschlossen!!\n\rBitte warte bis der Launcher die Dateien entpackt hat."); // Erklärt sich von selbst
    string ExistingZipFile = @"Test.zip";
    string sourceDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string TargetDirectory = (sourceDir + "minecraft.jar");
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
    {


        // ab hier komm der restliche script
        // bei dem man eig. nix einstellen soll 
        if (zip.ContainsEntry("Test.zip"))
        {
            zip.RemoveEntry("Test.zip");
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Entpacken der Dateien abgeschlossen!");
        label1.Text = "Entpacken abgeschlossen!";
    }


}
```

Comment: Where is it? It's `In der Box`

Comment: Maybe that's why Minecraft has a creature called a Enderman. It's en der, man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so i made this code for you...

```
if (Directory.Exists(temp))
    {
        Directory.Delete(temp, true);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(temp);
    }
    using (ZipFile jar = ZipFile.Read(appdata + "\\.minecraft\\bin\\minecraft.jar"))
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
        {
            zip.ExtractAll(temp, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
        }
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(temp))
        {
            if (jar.ContainsEntry(file))
            {
                jar.RemoveEntry(file);
            }
            jar.AddFile(file, "\\");
        }
        jar.Save();
        MessageBox.Show("Entpacken der Dateien abgeschlossen!");
        label1.Text = "Entpacken abgeschlossen!";Solved the problem with this code(thanks to GemHunter1 :D ):
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:** 
use this:

```
//filename_you_are_going_to_copy is string with name of file with extension, not full path
if (zip.ContainsEntry(filename_you_are_going_to_copy))
{
     zip.RemoveEntry(filename_you_are_going_to_copy);
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
after code above write this:

```
mod.AddFile(filename_you_are_going_to_copy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with this code(thanks to GemHunter1 :D ):

```
    if (Directory.Exists(temp))
    {
        Directory.Delete(temp, true);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(temp);
    }
    using (ZipFile jar = ZipFile.Read(appdata + "\\.minecraft\\bin\\minecraft.jar"))
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
        {
            zip.ExtractAll(temp, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
        }
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(temp))
        {
            if (jar.ContainsEntry(file))
            {
                jar.RemoveEntry(file);
            }
            jar.AddFile(file, "\\");
        }
        jar.Save();
        MessageBox.Show("Entpacken der Dateien abgeschlossen!");
        label1.Text = "Entpacken abgeschlossen!";
```